# how to add id and value to button with image?

Tags: html, reactjs

i have button that have id and value and accourding to this id&value i activate my 'on click event' as i need.

I add new image on this button - and now i looking for a way to add the id&value to this new image that i added - but i can't find any way to do it.

on code below - i gave 2 render methods 
    1. before add image 
    2. after add image (render1)

on the render1 ( rename to render and remark the other render method ) 
I can't get the id and value on the handleClick method.

the code:

```
    class myClass extends React.Component 
    {
      constructor(props) 
      {
        super(props);
      }

      handleClick(event)
      {
        const id = event.target.id;
        const value = event.target.value;

        // do something accourding to the target id and value
      }

      getElementType()
      {
         let elementType = null; 
         const i = this.element;

         switch(i)
         {
            case(1):
                elementType = 1;
                break;

            case(2):
                elementType = 2;
                break;

            case(3):
                elementType = 3;
                break;
         }
      }


      //render() 
      //{
    //      const elementType = this.getElementType();
    //  
    //      const itemToRender = items.map((item, i) =>
    //      <div>
    //          <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} id={i} value={elementType}> 
//                  {item.text}
//              </button> 
//          </div>);

  //          return itemToRender;

    //  }

      // after add the img
      render() 
      {
            const elementType = this.getElementType();

            const itemToRender = items.map((item, i) =>
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} id={i} value={elementType}> 
                    <img src={item.icon} /> 
                    {item.text}
                </button> 
            </div>);

            return itemToRender;

      }  
    }
```

Comment: what does the `render1()` used for?

Comment: @JeeMok as i explain - render1 is same as render but with image on the button - ( just delete the render and change the render1 name to render )

Comment: Why add a value and ID to the image? Clicking on the button and image should do different things?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings no, if you pressing the image you will find yourself calling the 'handleClick' but the id and target will be not with the value and is from the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) attribute to get the element to which the event handler is attached.

```
handleClick(event)
{
    const id = event.currentTarget.id;
    const value = event.currentTarget.value;

    // do something accourding to the target id and value
}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    const target = event.currentTarget.id;
    console.log(target);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
      {
        this.items.map((item, i)=>(
          <button id={i} key={i} onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <img src={item} alt="placeholder"/>
            {item}
          </button>
        ))
      }
      </main>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You don't need to add value to the image, `event.currentTarget` will give you the value attached to the button itself

Comment: The key on the image? The code snippet added shows retrieving the ID, but image does not have a key attached to it!

Comment: `event.currentTarget` will give you the element the event handler is attached to, so as long as `img` is inside the button you will get value and id of button itself